# Performance issue with VCLStyle on FormShow?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, vcl-styles

I want to set dynamically style on Form show event. There is too much control in the form, so the form is opened two times slower than Windows style.

How can i set style dynamically style? Like this first disable then enable?

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Are you sure this is why things are slow?  You get the form's OnShow event before anything is painted.  If you're sure the bottleneck is there, you could override CMShowingChanged to do stuff before the VCL does anything.

Comment: OnShow is too late. You need to change the style before the form is created; otherwise, it is destroyed and created again with the new style. (You can see this if you change the style in a button click event - the form disappears and then reappears with the new style.)

Comment: I override `Loaded` method.  i put before `inherited;` for disable style `TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Windows');` and Forms OnShow event for enable style  `TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('MyStyle');`. But shows this message `Cannot change Visible OnShow or OnHide`